# I'm having a problem with this array code that is supposed to output all the numbers that were input prior by the user

Tags: c++, arrays, output

So, this is how I want it to go:

I want my program to ask how many numbers the user will input(for example 5). After inputting the numbers, I want the program to output those numbers(2, 3, 20, 40, 50 for example).

Easy, right? Well I've got a problem with my code: even if I input 10 or 200 as the amount of numbers I will input, the program keeps stopping at the 6th number and outputs those 6 numbers only.

```
int main() 
{
    int arraySize;
    int array[arraySize];
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to visualize?" << endl << "Numbers: ";
    cin >> arraySize;
    cout << "You will visualize " << arraySize << " numbers." << endl << "Begin: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    cout << "You have inserted the following numbers: " << endl;

    for (int a = 0; a < arraySize; a++) {
        cout << array[a] << " ";
    }
}
```

If I input 10 as the arraySize, it'll stop at 6. Just to clarify,

Comment: You declare your array **before** you read it's size. It won't readjust it's length when the number changes.

Comment: Also, obligatory comment that Variable Length Arrays are not standard C++ and are only supported by some compilers as extension.

Comment: `int array[arraySize];` when this is executed `arraySize` has not been set. It is a garbage value. Also in Standard `c++` this type of array is illegal. `arraySize` must be a compile time constant by the language standard.

Comment: `arraySize` is unitialized. You have no idea what number is placed there. Then, you create an array of you-have-no-idea-what size. And then, you ask user to provide size for the array. But the array is already declared. The size of that array cannot change. It doesn't matter that `arraySize` changed, the size of array doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here:

```
int arraySize;
int array[arraySize];
```

Is not going to work. First of all, variable length arrays aren't part of C++, so it only compiles if the compiler tolerates it nevertheless. But another problem is that you're making the array with size of `arraySize`, but `arraySize` is not initialized. That's underfined behvaior - anything might happen and there's no guarantee whatsoever.

You need to read in the desired `arraySize` (with `cin >> arraySize;`) and **after** that you need to make your array. And when you do that, instead of a VLA, try something like this:

```
std::vector<int> array(arraySize);
```

Comment: A lot of people (including me) think it is (in most cases) useless to return in `main`. C++ doesn't require it anymore, therefore it is just noise (in most cases).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to determine the size of the array during *runtime* you need a container that is suitable for that. Since this question is tagged with C++, you should use some of the standard library containers.

In your case, `std::vector` is the best one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  size_t arraySize = 0;
  std::cout << "How many numbers would you like to visualize?\n"
            << "Numbers: ";
  std::cin >> arraySize;
  std::cout << "You will visualize " << arraySize << " numbers.\n"
            << "Begin: \n";

  // declare std::vector and allocate memory for arraySize elements
  std::vector<int> array(arraySize);
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    std::cin >> array[i];
  }
  std::cout << "You have inserted the following numbers: \n";

  for (int a = 0; a < array.size(); a++) {
    std::cout << array[a] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Think about that a user can still input whatever he likes, e.g., a string. An improvement (and a good practice) would be to *validate* the user input.

Using an approach where you define `int array[arraySize]` after you receive `arraySize` as user input does **not** solve your problem. Declaring variable length arrays is not valid C++. If you enable more compiler warnings you will get noticed about this.

E.g., using *gcc 8.2.0* with the flag `-Wpedantic` gives the following:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'array'
```

Comment: I need to study how vectors work before I can apply it to my codes. I'll be using this as an example for the future - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Itacool note that this is a misconception, you should have been studying c-arrays much more before using them, they are extremely complicated compared to `std::vector`. You dont need to know much more than presented in this answer to use a vector (of course you should read a bit more, but really not much).

Comment: @Itacool please consider the edit I made regarding variable length arrays.

Comment: @user463035818 That's good to know. I guess I'll be looking into them very soon then.

Comment: @datell Will do. Thanks.

Comment: @datell I enabled more compiler warnings and I did get that warning. Does that mean that the best way to do what I have in mind correctly (using the standard library containers) is by using std::vector?

Comment: @Itacool It is certainly a big hint to not use variable length arrays. You need to allocate memory *dynamically*. The (in most cases) best container for this is `std::vector`. So yes, stick to this.